Lineage change possibility
I formerly practiced with the local Shambhala group. I took my Refuge Vows there, received some random Buddhist name that had nothing to do with my studies or who I am; and was told I was now a member of Chogyam Trungpa's lineage.
Since then I found out about the disgusting sexual and physical abuse perpetrated by Chogyam Trungpa and his son, the current Sakyong, and have not been able to continue with the Shambhala teachings.
My question (and I apologize for its being so very basic) is: can a refugee somehow change lineages? I asked this of an older woman there whom I respected,and she said no without any explanation.
I now am studying the teachings of H.H. the Dalai Lama, and do not really know what tradition I am in. I have practiced on my own -- with the exception of my few Shambhala years -- for about 20 years, but am not very knowledgeable about the scriptures. Any link to a good beginner's guide would be much appreciated. I hope I have not violated any rules.
And thanks in advance for any answers. I really don't want to be associated with Shambhala in any way. If there is a way to change my lineage, I'd really like to know.

You're in the tradition of Buddhism. If you find a good teacher, it's natural you'd want to stay with them, but that doesn't mean you're forbidden to learn from anyone else. Cults use fear based mind control schemes to keep you from leaving, and keep you isolated from outside information and people. The fear based mental prison is created by telling people something bad will happen if they don't believe this or do that. If you can manipulate how someone feels, then you can control how they think and act, because emotion overrides reason in all of us, some of the time, and in a lot of people, critical thinking is virtually nonexistent.
But no one owns you. In the old days, in China at least, it was common for a monk to stay at a monastery awhile and then journey to another when they thought their practice had gone stale, or sometimes the abbot would recommend they go to a certain teacher or hermit. It was common enough to have a name, "foot traveling monk" or "hsing chiao".
It may be that Transmission is real, but you're not going to get it from someone you've already identified as an abusive cultist. It seems to me that the value of lineage is largely in the quality control, not in a magical association with a certain group. In a proper lineage it's assumed each successor is Enlightened to some degree, and will in turn set up other qualified teachers, so it's safer to trust them.

+1 indeed the Buddha taught in AN3:66 the importance of evaluating teachings based on observations and verifications.

Thank you both.

In the Visuddhimagga, the change of lineage appears to be a stage just before stream entry. Similarly in his talks, Ajahn Chah used the word Gotrabhū citta and Gotrabhū puggala (i.e. change-of-lineage) to describe a person whose mind had a temporary taste of the Deathless (i.e. a stream winner).
This may not be in line with the definition or usage of the term in Tibetan Buddhism but I find it to be more logical and rational. Our bodies’ lineage is tied to our parents and cannot change. Similarly, the lineage of our practices and habits are deeply influenced by our teachers (spiritual, educational, parental and so on).
However, our minds’ lineage once tied to the Deathless, no longer identify with the world. It is for this reason that one of the fetters broken by the stream winner is clinging to rites and rituals. A mind thus freed, no longer cling to practices and beliefs that belonged to the world. It instead relies on the Dharma, karma and reality to guide its growth and development. It does not seek or cling anymore to a permanent self or hope that there is something constant, indestructible and unchanging within the conventional self. This is because such a mind had given up on finding such a thing in the world; it has already found it beyond - in the Deathless.

A mind thus freed, no longer cling to practices and beliefs that belonged to the world.". Does this include meditation?

Yes. Meditation is a tool/practice that belongs to the world as does virtues and wisdom. The noble eightfold path (virtues, concentration and wisdom) is also of the world but is needed to attain Nirvana.

This forum is about Buddhism rather than about specific personality cults.
While Chogyam Trungpa was not a monk, any monk in Buddhism that has sex is defeated & ceases to be a monk. Similarly, any person that habitually often engaged in sexual misconduct obviously cannot be an object of refuge in Buddhism.
In Buddhism, be it Theravada or Mahayana, there are Three Refuges, which are:

The Buddha

The Dhamma (which prohibits sexual misconduct).

The Sangha (who have realised the Noble Path or realised luminous mind).


Those committing sexual misconduct cannot be Sangha; thus cannot be a refuge.
A 'refuge' means an object or place of 'safety'.
My impression is the FPMT was/is a very ethical Tibetan lineage. I suggest to consider discussing your concerns with them.

Thank you so much. I had always had reservations about Chogyam Trungpa, and whether his teachings were legitimate.I am very sorry to have written an inappropriate question, and will gladly check out the link you provided.

@FarishCunning I don't think it's an inappropriate question.

Yes, you can switch between different schools. Generally it is not recommended, because re-establishing a connection with root guru requires a lot of work. Also, mixing different teachings can be ineffective or dangerous, like mixing drugs from 2 different doctors.
Of course, in cases where you found out that your teacher was fake, you have no choice but to switch to another one.
The best book for beginners I can name is Illuminating the path to Enlightenment by Dalai Lama.

"Lineage" is specific to Tibetan buddhism.
From the perspective of that sect, that guy is your "root guru".
I actually kind of like his whole crazy wisdom teachings, especially seeing I too am a degenerate sex addict who likes to intoxicate myself lol.
The idea is from tilopa "the problem is not pleasure, the problem is attachments" If you can have sex and get drunk without attachments then there is no issue. This is actually in line with the Buddhas teachings. Just intoxicaton can (possibly) lead to headlessness and other lacking of sila, and ultimately sensory pleasures are just idle distractions.
As for changing lineages, it is perfectly fine to learn from other teachers, even though some sects in tibet (especially gelug) frown upon it, but even tsongkharpa learned from many teachers; tilopa, naropa learned from many teachers too.
But the lineage of tilops-milarepa that kaguya comes from is wholly dependant upon teacher-student transmission. Normally kaguya won't teach you the depths of the teachings (like transference of consciousness in the 6 yogas of naropa) until you have dedicated yourself to the kaguya path for X amount of years. The lineage is oral too. Most of what you can learn there is not written down anywhere to find. Or at least their "secrets"
Obviously theravada doesn't have any doctrine like that: you learn under a preceptor, sure -- but all the teachings come from the Buddha, the 4 nikayas. There are many ex-mahayana ordained monks and nuns who give up mahayana and seek theravada. Again, nothing about lineage preventing you from doing so.

2nd noble truth contradicts what you are saying. Even the Buddha himself was able to abide in jhanic bliss, this itself is a sensation (psychosomatic feeling) piti and sukha themselves are in turn feelings, sensory experiences. Again, 2nd noble truth. The issue is attachment, not the experience of pleasure. If there was an issue with experiencing pleasure, well defecating or sneezing gives us pleasure...So does eating or drinking, so life itself is attachment. Again, it IS in line with the Buddhas teachings. Attachment is the issue, not pleasure itself.

Pleasure and delight are not the same. Arhants can experience pleasure and pain. Nibanna is not eradication of pleasure or pain, it is the cessation of suffering. An arhant can still experience pleasure from an orgasm or pain when his arm is chopped off. So why do you then think an arhant cannot experience pleasure in sexual intercourse or intoxication. I understand what you mean in delight. The delight for sensory experience itself is attachment. Sights, sounds etc, but the experience of say a cat rubbing against your leg, which gives pleasure doesnt then mean that is attachment. It is just..

An experience of pleasure. Again as tilopa said "the problem is not pleasure the problem is attachments" and essentially this is the karma kaguya philosophy as that is it's lineage. Hence why these monks do in fact get married, have sex and it is permissible for them to take intoxicants.  This is multiple phenomena. Attachments, pleasure (and pain by extension) delight none of which are synonymous though are intertwined and difficult to discriminate in our mental continuum.

Think of the 12 dependant  links. (I will link the website after this post). Sensation "vedana" can be pleasurable, unpleasurable and neutral. So an experience of say orgasm, breathing and physical pain respectively. THEN comes thirst/desire (I assume what you are explaining as delight) "trishna"....See the experience of pleasure in of itself is just a sensory experience(s) they inherently are NOT attachments. They are just sensations. So again in turn as tilopa said "the problem is not pleasure, it is attachments"

https://encyclopediaofbuddhism.org/wiki/Twelve_links_of_dependent_origination#Vedana_(sensation)

What, then, of the precepts?  Is it only attachment to them, not the precepts themselves, with which we should be concerned?

You should probably ask this question as a question itself as it is completely off topic though the precepts would only be a method of avoiding negativity, they are neither attachments nor inherently a method to avoid attachments.
